# How can I know the font size (or percent) of the iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I wanna know the font size (or percent) of the iOS with Swift? I know that by using dynamic types a label adjust itself, but I wanna know what percent is it, is it to the minimum, to the maximum, in the middle?

Image sample:
[image: Image Sample]

Comment: OS? Care to explain what that acronym means?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson the image it is pretty self-explanatory. OP wants to know the value which the user has set that slider to.

Comment: @LeoDabus then would you mind explaining the acronym? Using non-standard or home made acronyms is a good way to make a question harder to understand.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson OS? operating System? iOS?

Comment: https://stablekernel.com/supporting-accessibility-larger-text-in-ios/

Comment: Well then that sentence, "font size of the OS", didn't make much sense, if that was what it meant.

Comment: IMHO It seems obvious what OS or iOS means even to non-tech people who do not visit this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this extension:

```swift
extension UITraitEnvironment {
    func printCurrentContentSizeCategory() {
        switch traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory {
        case .extraSmall:
            print("extra small")
        case .small:
            print("small")
        case .medium:
            print("medium")
        case .large:
            print("large")
        case .extraLarge:
            print("extra large")
        case .extraExtraLarge:
            print("extra extra large")
        case .extraExtraExtraLarge:
            print("extra extra extra large")
        case .accessibilityMedium:
            print("accessibility medium")
        case .accessibilityLarge:
            print("accessibility large")
        case .accessibilityExtraLarge:
            print("accessibility extra large")
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraLarge:
            print("accessibility extra extra large")
        case .accessibilityExtraExtraExtraLarge:
            print("accessibility extra extra extra large")
        default:
            print("Unspecified")
        }
    }
}
```

And now you can use it in any `UIViewController`, `UIView`, etc:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    printCurrentContentSizeCategory()
}
```